# BecomeNextResponder on UITextField in custom table cells in UIViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

This seems like it should be really straight forward, but for some reason I'm missing it...so any help is appreciated.

So, I've got a UIViewController with a UITableView embedded which has 2 custom cells. This is a login view, so obviously the 2 cells are username and password.

The cells each have a UITextField, which is defined in a UITableViewCell class.

What I am trying to do is when the keyboard return button is pressed when on the username text field, the password textfield becomes first responder. When the return button is pressed on the password text field, it should run some logic to login or not.

Pretty straight forward.

I have tried lots of different messy workarounds that I thought would work, but nothing quite has.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add the indexpath (row or section) of the cell as tag for the textfield. So when the textfield resigns firstresponder, you have the current indexpath and can get the next cell (cellForRowAtIndexPath:). Then you can get the textfield of this cell and set it as firstresponder.

Do you need code examples?